# Regular Expression with exactly 2 uppercase letters and 3 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match words that contains **exactly** 2 uppercase letters and 3 numbers. Numbers and uppercase letters can be at any positions in the word.

> HelLo1aa2s3d: true
>
> WindowA1k2j3: true
>
> AAAsjs21js1: false
>
> ASaaak12: false

My regex attempt, but only matches exactly 2 uppercase letters:

```
([a-z]*[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*){2}
```

Comment: "uppercase numbers"? What is an uppercase number?

Comment: To clarify, a string with 3 uppercase letters or 4 numbers would disqualify? That is, there must be exactly 2 uppercase letters and exactly 3 numbers in the string?

Comment: yes! >AAAsjs21js1: false

Comment: [**Bobble Bubble**'s solution is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240371/3832970).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex **[lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**:

```
/^(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){2})(?!(?:.*[A-Z].*){3,})(?=(?:.*\d.*){3})(?!(?:.*\d.*){4,}).*$/gm
```

Explanation:

```
^                     // assert position at beginning of line
(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){2})  // positive lookahead to match exactly 2 uppercase letters
(?!(?:.*[A-Z].*){3,}) // negative lookahead to not match if 3 or more uppercase letters
(?=(?:.*\d.*){3})     // positive lookahead to match exactly 3 digits
(?!(?:.*\d.*){4,})    // negative lookahead to not match if 4 or more digits
.*                    // select all of non-newline characters if match
$                     // end of line
/gm                   // flags: "g" - global; "m" - multiline
```

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tN0gE3/2)**

Comment: They can be at any positions, not necessarily consecutive.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the catch. Fixed.

Comment: This does not fit the "exactly" part of the requirement.

Comment: I'll revise the solution. I went with the assumption that OP meant at least.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `String.match` function:

```
function checkWord(word) {
    var numbers = word.match(/\d/g), letters = word.match(/[A-Z]/g);

    return (numbers.length === 3 && letters.length === 2) || false;
}

console.log(checkWord("HelLo1aa2s3d"));  // true
console.log(checkWord("WindowA1k2j3"));  // true
console.log(checkWord("AAAsjs21js1"));   // false
console.log(checkWord("ASaaak12"));      // false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need just one lookahead.

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$)(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}[^A-Z]*$
```

- `\d` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digit. `\D` is the negation of `\d` and matches a non-digit
- `(?=` opens a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `(?:` opens a [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group).
- At `^` start `(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$)` looks ahead for exactly three digits until `$` the [end](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
- If the condition succeeds `(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}[^A-Z]*` matches a string with exactly two upper alphas until `$` end. `[^` opens a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mC3nT6/1)

If you want to allow only alphanumeric characters, replace `[^A-Z]` with `[a-z\d]` [like in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK5yO7/1).

Answer (score -1):

#### Without lookahead, pure regex:

http://regexr.com/3ddva

Basically, just checks every case.